# C# GridView / RadioButton is not fireing an event... why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with rows of data and a group of radio buttons for each row that can be selected.  But when selected the event never fires for the radio dropdown.... why?

```
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoV"
 runat="server" Checked='<%#
 Bind("VOID") %>' AutoPostBack="True" 
         oncheckedchanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged"
                                     GroupName='<%# BIND("WallstreetID")
 %>' />
                             </ItemTemplate>
        protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not re-databinding the grid in the Page_Load event without checking for IsPostBack.  That could wipe out your other events internal to the grid.